# FPS rate is dropping in android portrait mode vs landscape

Tags: android, performance, surfaceview, frame-rate, landscape-portrait

It seems that i got FPS drop between landscape and portrait modes. The reason is background image, but i just can't understand why landscape mode would be faster compared to portrait.

Here is a part that defines background image: (separated from onDraw)

```
Bitmap tempbit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.background_4_png);
Bitmap mBackgroundImage=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempbit, (int)screenWidth, (int)screenHeight, false);
```

I have to define rectangle objects as this is a fastest method for drawing the background according to my tests:

```
src.set(0, 0, (int)screenWidth, (int)screenHeight);
dst.set(0,0,(int)screenWidth,(int)screenHeight);
```

Here is the onDraw:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(this.mBackgroundImage,src,dst,null);
```

In this case, ANY original image will be drawn faster in ladscape mode compared to portrait.

I've tried:

- `canvas.drawBitmap(this.mBackgroundImage,0,0,null)`
- minimized image size

but results are the same - framedrop in portrait mode.

Appreciate any help, thanx

Device I'm running on is Samsung S4.

Comment: Some code/more details might be helpful.

Comment: sry, just added more information - the issue is background image, but still can't figure out why such a big difference between ladscape vs portrait orientations....

Comment: still having this issue! Somehow, ladscape mode always delivers higher FPS. (Portrait 45fps, Ladscape 60fps) this is for doing exactly same caculations.

Comment: after disabling all logic except for the background painting, fps is still dropping in protrait mode and increases in ladnscape.

Comment: removing all logic and background draw, ladscape and portrait views running on same fps (60-61)

Comment: I have a similar problem, but I am only drawing text. The text size is dynamically altered each frame, so it is fairly intensive, but it runs perfectly smoothly in landscape, and jitters in portrait. Hope someone answers this question soon; if I find a solution, I'll do so myself.